# Find average (AVG) when year selected from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, average

I have a table that echos 12 values for the year 2017 Jan- Dec.

Trouble is, we are only in August and my present code (which works fine for 2016 as all values are not null)  keeps dividing the value by 12..when it needs to be 8 (August) and then 9 for September etc.

Any ideas how I get the average for what I need and not for the 12 months.

```
$sql = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(valuations),2) AS value_sum FROM office_figures2016 where date_figures =2017";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo "<td> " . $row["value_sum"]."</td>";
```

Comment: Something like `SUM(col)/ MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())`??

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any data belonging to future date then you can use the following query to get the running average:

```
$sql = "SELECT ROUND(SUM(valuations)/MONTH(NOW()), 2) AS value_sum 
    FROM office_figures2016 
    WHERE date_figures =2017";
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:     i inncluded the rest of my query above to see if supposed to change the 'if' statement that is being traced to the error line of code

Comment: no , same error. what does the month(now) do? my dates are pre entered with datepicker not timestamped if that helps?

Comment: It was a typo, try now?

Comment: awesome  thanks,,i did have  a play with the brackets but i couldnt get them in right place ...

Comment: i ve worked out this obviosuly divides the number of entries i have by the live date of (now).. how would i just add the entries that are actually in the table...does this go back to query that divides the not null entries?

Comment: If you just want to add the entries then you can remove `/MONTH(NOW()` part from `SELECT` query

Comment: and that adds them up not averages... i replace sum by avg and am back to where i started. i.e. it divideds by 12 and not by the amount entered. i.e. NOT NULL

Comment: this doesnt work either:    $sql = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(valuations),2) AS value_sum FROM office_figures2016 where date_figures =2017 IS NOT NULL";

Answer (score 1):

Why not excluding `null` entries from your request ?

```
$sql = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(valuations),2) AS value_sum FROM office_figures2016 WHERE date_figures = 2017 AND valuations != NULL";
```

Comment: that gives me a no value (blank space)  in the average cell.

Comment: @glen Why did you try to edit my answer while removing the relevant part ? Did you try my query or the version you replaced my answer with ?

Comment: i updated your post and not mine..admin error.  any reason why its blank? ive worked out that even though i have july - dec as empty ,, they may not be null..  cant work out why

Comment: @Glen Can't you check what value they have ?

Comment: yes, i used this in the end as the values werent null (even though empty).                      $sql = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(valuations),2) AS value_sum FROM office_figures2016 WHERE date_figures =2017 AND valuations IS NOT NULL AND valuations!= ''  ";

Comment: @glen Does it work ? If so, write your own answer or I'll edit mine, so that the answer is on this page for later use.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me . It seems it was all to do with null and not null . Database wasnt seeing my empty cells as null so kept returning 12 rows instead of desired 6.

SELECT * FROM office_figures 2016 WHERE date_figures=2017 AND firsts IS NOT NULL AND firsts != ''

thanks to David Alves and ks john who wasnt to know my cells were not null.